# Main query results use again in Subquery

Tags: sql

I have a improve issue for this Sql:

```
select
    A.id,
    ...
from
    pub_log A
where
    1 = 1
    and A.scope >= 2
    and A.exeby >= 2
    and A.executioner not in (
        select
            B.executioner
        from
            pub_log B
        where
            A.executioner in (
                'somename'
            )
            and (
                A.scope = 0
                or A.scope = 2
            )
    )
order by
    A.create_date desc limit 20 offset 0
```

I am using in PostgreSQL,in this query 
I query two times in one select on the same table 
In the action ,this is to waste 
So how can I improve this sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hej,

You can not really improve the query in that way 2 times query the same table.
You need the subquery because of you dont got the information about executioner.

Hope got your question right :-)
Sorry for bad London

Comment: Thank you,I spite the SQL and use PK to solution this issue,may I asking you is my sql O(n2)  now?
If I have subquery in SQL like that , what is my O(n)

Comment: No problem thx the help. I know what you mean with O(x) things i am not into this i can not really help you there sry

Comment: Thank you any way!